# How to prove that regular polygons have the greatest area to perimeter ratio?

Tags: calculus, geometry, reference-request, maxima-minima, area

When I was studying calculus, all the geometry problems that asked for the maximum area of a $k$-polygon given a fixed perimeter, or the minimum perimeter of a $k$-polygon given a fixed area, would always have the regular $k$-polygon as the solution.
After a lot of exercises, I noticed that this always held true, so I assumed that it was a general fact and used it as a shortcut for giving the correct answer. However, I was not able to prove or disprove this assumption, so I want to ask here for a proof.

Although this result was not mentioned in my book, I still think it is true and had been discovered centuries ago, so I want to ask who was the first person to have ever discovered this and proven it. (Since this problem is elementary I think it is probably Newton or someone who came before Newton.)

Comment: Search "isoperimetric inequality for polygons". One hit here: https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/2523/ There is probably an answer on this site but I can't find it.

Comment: Viktor Blåsjö's 2005 *American Mathematical Monthly* article "The Evolution of the Isoperimetric Problem" (available [here](https://maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/the-evolution-of-the-isoperimetric-problem) via maa.org) is pretty comprehensive, but gets a bit advanced in discussing the general cases.

Comment: @Blue what is the prerequisites to read this article ? I only know some analysis and have read only 2 books (Baby rudin and robert bartle  introduction to real analysis )

Comment: @pie: *"what is the prerequisites to read this article ?"* ... Just keep reading until it stops making sense. :)

Comment: @Blue I am doing that right now But I was afraid that in page 20 or something I find Algebraic topology and some other stuff that I don't understand : ) so it would be a kind of wasting time